# How can I split paragraph into one-line-per-sentence but still keep it wrapped visually?

Tags: fill-paragraph, line-break, display

This is similar to [Editing files with one-sentence-per-line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/443/2264) (in function as well as motive), but I wish to have a full, flowing paragraph rather than visual breaks at every sentence.

I would like to have a minor mode that, when active, will visually join lines from the same paragraph (not separated by `\n\n` or `paragraph-separate` or ...) and then activate behavior (perhaps derived from `visual-line-mode`) that will wrap the line without actually inserting `\n`.

Does such a mode exist?  If not, how would I go about the process of altering a paragraph's display properties to achieve the result?  (After all, this is the crux of such a mode and one could be developed from the snippet.)

Comment: [...] will visually join [...].  Do you mean keep the underlying `\n` (if present), or do you want it to actually remove the newlines to provide 1-paragraph-per-line?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `buffer-display-table` to make the new-lines `\n` appear to be something else like spaces or something -- see the following example in the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24842771/2112489  The advantage with this would be that the text in the document is **not** modified. The new line can be just about anything -- e.g., a smiley face, spaces, a pilcrow symbol, etc.  The visual effect is that wrapping will occur.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin I want to keep the newlines where present.  In fact, I would like to force the newline on a sentence-end, but this can be done via separate hook.

Comment: @lawlist the visual effect is that newlines will be gone everywhere, isn't it? Won't all paragraphs be collapsed into one?

Comment: @Malabarba -- Yes, that is correct -- it affects the whole buffer.  I guess a workaround might be to use a special symbol to separate paragraphs -- e.g., form-feed or something like that, and turn that form-feed into a visual `\n` using the `buffer-display-table`.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to this request but think that the minor-mode described by OP is not the correct solution.  The underlying problem is that diff doesn't work well for text as it was designed for code.  Working around this issue in Emacs is a possible but not a clean solution for various reasons.  It would be much better to improve diff to work well with text.

Comment: @tmalsburg Good point. I wonder if there any such difftools – but I further wonder if `git` would work with it.  Regardless, it's still an interesting question. :)

Comment: You might find this package https://github.com/andersjohansson/tex-fold-linebreaks interesting

Answer (score 3):

As Tom said, putting a display property on the newlines will kind of work.

The problem is to  figure out which lines to wrap.

Here is an example to get you started:

```el
(let ((eol-regexp "[[:graph:]] ?\\(\n\\)[^\t\n ]"))
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
   `((,eol-regexp 1 '(face default display " ")))))

(visual-line-mode 1)
```

This will "remove" newlines if it is preceded by graphical characters and the next line is not indented or empty. You will have to experiment to find something that works for you.

Some more explanations:

1. `font-lock-add-keywords` adds a list of rules to font locking (so font lock must be enabled. The first argument can be a mode (e.g. `text-mode`); in our case it is nil, which means add the rule only for the current buffer.
2. Our "rule" is `(,eol-regexp 1 '(face default display " "))`. The first element is the regular expression we built earlier; the second is the subexpression we are interested in; the third is the "face" we want to apply.
3. While using a face for the newlines is of no use for us, we can also add text properties. So we use the default face and than add a display property witch replaces the substring 1 (i.e. the newline) with a space.
4. If you shoot yourself in the foot, delete the buffer or remove the keyword with `font-lock-remove-keywords`.
5. You might also want to add `display` to `font-lock-extra-managed-props` (I have not tried this).
6. The tricky part is to get the regexp right. "\(\n\)[^\n]" would match any newline that is not immediatly followed by another one. ".\{30,\}\(\n\)" would only match newlines preceeded by at least 30 characters.

Comment: One can find an implementation of the above as a package at https://github.com/andersjohansson/tex-fold-linebreaks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, it is that you would like to preserve all the newlines in the buffer as they are; but you would like to display some of them as spaces.  Then, you'd like word-wrapping.

For word-wrapping I think you can use `visual-line-mode`.

For dealing with the newlines, I think you could perhaps put a `display` property with `" "` (a string consisting of a single space) as a value on the newlines you want to display differently.