# A possible incompatibility between `toggle-frame-maximized` and a mode using `visual-line-mode`

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, debugging

I have `(toggle-frame-maximized)` in my init file. If I enable the `ospl-mode` (btw very handy mode) given in the answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/473/, then I minimize the frame, Emacs (GNU Emacs 24.5.1) get frozen. Any idea why this happens? I also checked this with `emacs -Q` the same happens.

**Edit 1:** The OS is windows, for minimizing I click on the middle icon of the bar of emacs window (see the image below)

[image]

**Edit 2:** It seems that I have localized the problem a little more, if I do the following steps Emacs get frozen (unresponsive), I am wondering if other people can test the following steps to see what happens for them.

1. Start with `emacs -Q`
2. Eval `(toggle-frame-maximized)`
3. Then Eval all of

   `(visual-line-mode 1)
       (setq right-margin-width (- (window-body-width)  fill-column))
       (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer))`
4. Click on the icon which looks like a `double overlapping squares` (see the above image, the icon between `-` and `X`).

Comment: What command do you use to *minimize the frame*, and what operating system please?

Comment: @lawlist I added the information the you have requested.

Comment: Is it possible to type `C-g` one or more times to get Emacs to unfreeze and become functional again?  [Perhaps it's a never-ending loop issue -- there are three (3) `while` loops in the linked thread.]

Comment: @lawlist thank you for your interest. After several `C-g` or even `C-]`, emacs is still frozen.

Comment: If you can give a reproducible recipe starting from `emacs -Q` then please consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Of course, you will want to dig into the `ospl-mode` code a bit to simplify the recipe. IOW, preferably, the recipe won't require loading that library. But if you can't do that then still consider filing a bug report.  Emacs should not "freeze". (But determine what "freeze" means - if it is just in an infloop due to the code in `ospl-mode` then that's probably a library problem, not an Emacs problem.)

Comment: @drew Following your suggestions, I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your recipe seems simple enough to report this as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Be sure to keep the info that that command provides automatically in the report buffer, especially the Emacs version.

FWIW, following that recipe I do not see the problem on MS Windows (Windows 7).

I typed all of that into `*scratch*` and then evaluated the first sexp. I selected the other sexps and did `M-x eval-region`. I minimized the window-mgr window using the window-mgr `-` button in the frame title bar. I had no problem restoring the window and using it normally.

So I'm guessing that this is either related to your particular Emacs version (e.g. build) or platform.

Please do report the bug, if it is reproducible for you.

Comment: Drew, to minimize the window one should click on the icon between `-` and `×` which looks like an square (not `-`).

Comment: Not in MS Windows -- not in mine, at least. The square is `Maximize`, and when maximized it is replaced by two overlapping squares, to `Restore Dow`n. The `-` is `Minimize`, and the `X` is delete.

Comment: What I meant by *minimizing* was clicking on that *two overlapping squares*.

Comment: OK (that's Restore. Doing that I still do not see a problem, on Windows 7. Same comment as before: please consider reporting the bug to Emacs Dev. Thx.